# Troubleshoot create-react-app build SCSS Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs, build, compiler-errors, core-ui

I'm deploying my first react web app, but I'm running into this error:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/scss/style.scss
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 62
```

I started it using `create-react-app`, and added CoreUI. `npm start` compiles and runs great in the browser. When I inspect `style.scss` from the browser, I get this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
* CoreUI - HTML, CSS, and JavaScript UI Components Library
* @version v4.2.6
* @link https://coreui.io/
* Copyright (c) 2022 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek
* License MIT  (https://coreui.io/license/)
*/
:root {
  --cui-blue: #0d6efd;
  --cui-indigo: #6610f2;
  --cui-purple: #6f42c1;
  --cui-pink: #d63384;
  --cui-red: #dc3545;
  --cui-orange: #fd7e14;
  --cui-yellow: #ffc107;
  --cui-green: #198754;
  --cui-teal: #20c997;
  --cui-cyan: #0dcaf0;
  --cui-black: #000015;
  --cui-white: #ffffff;
```

I don't see anything that looks like a culprit.
I've looked in the build folder, and it's not producing a `style.scss` file.
Beyond looking at that, I really don't know how to figure out what might be causing that error.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using React 18 and are using `.scss` files like with CoreUI, then you'll need to install `node-sass` which is currently version 8.

`npm install node-sass` OR `yarn add node-sass`

Additionally, `node-sass 8` does not play well with `react-scripts 4`. You'll want to replace that with `react-scripts 5`:

`npm uninstall react-scripts` OR `yarn remove react-scripts`

Then:

`npm install react-scripts` OR `yarn add react-scripts` (Should now be v5)

Now CoreUI and any .scss files should play nicely. Here's an example sandbox I created using React 18, Node-Sass 8, React Scripts 5, CoreUI 4.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keen-smoke-t12xz8

I can see how initial CRA would cause this issue since it's currently shipping with `react-scripts 4`.

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the track, in the end I had to update all of my dependencies, update react to 18 and it's building beautifully now!